# Correctly save datas locally in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project where all the user datas are saved locally inside a `.txt` file with json format. My question is how to optimize the datas reading/writing, I mean: this project includes a program, when the program is running it starts by reading the files ( in the file are stored profiles infos ) `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(PROFILES_FL, 'utf-8'));` and during the process it edits them too`fs.writeFileSync(path, content, 'utf8');`, but the editing consists in change a parameter of a profile and writing again in the file all the profiles datas again. If there are few datas it is fast but i think that when the datas start to grow the process is slower and slower. How can I optimize this?

I'm using `Node.js`

Comment: Well, when the data start to grow, you should consider using an actual DBMS.

Comment: @MEDZ yes but my problem is that i don't want to handle users datas so i want to store them locally and avoid the data handling in a database

Comment: Did you considered storing the data on the client using localStorage?

Comment: @MEDZ yes but the data sizes are bigger than the localstorage max size ( 10MB)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using redis as a caching storage instead of file it's made to be faster than database.

1) Install Redis on linux. Use this [simple guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04).

2) install redis with node using NPM: `npm install redis`

3) Require and initiate redis in your code:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); // this creates a new client
```

4) Quick start with redis:

```
let user_object = {username: 'medz', password: '*****'}
client.set('user_data', user_object);

client.get('user_data', function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('User data ->' + result);
});
```

You can check [this link](https://hackernoon.com/using-redis-with-node-js-8d87a48c5dd7) to know more about this process.